# How to implement remove() method in an array-based list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist

I'm new to Python and I  am just starting to learn how to use classes in Python. So I have a class called list and I'm trying to implement the `remove()` method.

If `a_list=[1,3,3,3,2]` then  `a_list.remove(3)` suppose to give me 1,3,3,2. However, the remove method I have written outputs `a_list=[1,3,2]`.

It seems that the method I have written will put an instance of any duplicated number in the output list. This is my `remove()` method.

```
 def remove(self, item):
    index=0
    if item not in self.array:
        raise ValueError("Item not in list")
    while index<len(self):
        if self.array[index]==item:
            for i in range(index,self.count-1):
                self.array[i]=self.array[i+1]
            self.count-=1
        index+=1
```

where `self.count` refers to the next available position in the list. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to break/return from the while loop after an item is found.

Comment: Do you know that remove is inbuilt method of python? you can use it as a_list.remove(3). Still you want to create a function? I think it's west of time you should develop something else that doesn't exist in python.

Comment: @poming alright thanks I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is wondering where to put the break statement:

```
def remove(self, item):
    index=0
    if item not in self.array:
        raise ValueError("Item not in list")
    while index<len(self):
        if self.array[index]==item:
            break
        index+=1

    for i in range(index,self.count-1):
        self.array[i]=self.array[i+1]
    self.count-=1
```